# Call a function using value from variable

Tags: python, django

I want to get a model in django using the current url

for example

`a =  resolve(request.path_info).url_name`

`context = { 'example' : a.objects.all }`

here the retrieved url name is available in models

This obivously won't work but this is what I want to accomplish

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [mre] and readk [ask] to provide all the details needed to help you.

Comment: Don't recommend doing this. Obviously the amount of models one has is finite, hence the number of urls / views you have to write is also finite. What is the problem with writing your views / urls explicitly? Your approach only increases complexity and introduces new bugs. As a matter of fact you can simply reuse your view after writing one (Class based views) and pass parameters while writing the url `MyView.as_view(model=SomeModel)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the request's resolver via `request.resolver_match`. See the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match) for more info. That can give you better access to the resolver than looking it up again.

Once you have that you can look up the model using the `AppConfig.get_model` method.

```
from django.apps import apps
ModelClass = apps.get_model(app_name, model_name)
```

Or

```
ModelClass = apps.get_model(f'{app_name}:{model_name}')
```